# Unable to implement logout function unable to navigate to login screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to navigate to Login Screen after clicking logout in headerRight but it isn't navigating but it is navigating to other routes expect login and otp.
i am not able to figure out why it isnt going to login or otp screen if it does got all other screens.

my main App

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
const Stack=new createNativeStackNavigator();
const App=()=>{
    return(
        <Context.Provider value={{islogin,setislogin,mail,setmail,pin,setpin,token,settoken}}>
        <NavigationContainer static>
            <Stack.Navigator static initialRouteName={islogin?'Home':'Login'}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{title:'Login',headerBackVisible:false}}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Otp" component={Otp} options={{title:'Otp',headerBackVisible:false}}/>
                <Stack.Group static screenOptions={({navigation,route})=>({headerRight:()=>{
                    if(!islogin)
                        return null;
                    return <Text onPress={()=>{//setislogin(false)
                        return navigation.navigate('Login')
                        }}>logout</Text>
                    }})}>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{title:'Home',headerBackVisible:false}}/> 
                    <Stack.Screen name="Result" component={Result}/>
                </Stack.Group>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Login.js

```
const App =  ({navigation}) => {
  const {setmail,setpin}=useContext(Context)
  useEffect(()=>{
            navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
          })
        })
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Login </Text>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.inputText}
        placeholder="PIN"
        placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
        onChangeText={text => setState({...state,pin:text})}
        value={state['pin']}/>
      </View>
    <View style={styles.inputView}>
    <TextInput
    style={styles.inputText}
    placeholder="Email"
    placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
    onChangeText={text => setState({...state,email:text})}
    value={state['email']}/>
    </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress = {onPressLogin}
      style={styles.loginBtn}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

removed import statements for better code